# NodeJS + TypeScript + Webpack4: Access to webpack application variables for non-web NodeJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

Because I don't want multiple output files  (compiled TypeScript files), I am considering the **webpack** usage for non-web NodeJS applications. If just build below **node_modules/some_dependency/index.ts** by **Webpack**, **Dependency** class it will not available in **index.babel.js** because webpack application has not global variables by default.

### index.babel.js

```
require('@babel/register');

// node_modules/some_dependency/index.js (compiled TypeScript)
import Dependency form 'dependency'; // Error!

new Dependency();
```

### node_modules/some_dependency/index.ts

```
export default class Dependency() {
   // ---
}
```

Could NodeJS module (**index.babel.js**) see `Dependency` if just to use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)?

Answer (score 0):

The minimal **webpack.confing.js** will be:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './TypeScriptSource/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: __dirname,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  }
};
```

Now, if class `Dependency` in `TypeScriptSource/index.ts` has `export default`, below code in `index.babel.js` will work:

```
require('@babel/register');

import Dependency from 'some-depencency';
new Dependency();
```

Required dependencies for `index.babel.js`:

```
"@babel/core": "7.1.2",
"@babel/node": "7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.1.0",
"@babel/register": "7.0.0",
```